# Single or Multiple logger instance in a web project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, sinatra

I'm work on build a log system in my project, which is a Ruby Web App base on Sinatra, similar with Rails.

I've referenced a lot of logging framework on Github, like sinatra/logger, logging, semantic logger, and I've saw some usage of Rails.

Many logging framework write that we should create many log instance for every class, to control the log level individually by each class when debugging, I don't know what the benefit it is. I think it's enough that we can change the log level dynamic by reading the log level from config file.

When I was developing android project, We are using a single log instance, and all place call the static method like "MyLog.info", this solution can let me control and format logs in one place, I think this is the benefit that create only one log instance in a project.

Additional, I saw the usage of Rails, it also has only one instance named Rails.logger, wherever place I want write log, I call Rails.logger.info "xxxxx",
this is very easy.

If I write many logger for each class, I should write many duplicate code for the logs, I'm doubting about this, could anyone tell me which one is better or how could I choose.

Comment: Are you asking how to enable logging in Sinatra per class?

Comment: No, I'm asking when we build a web project, we have two ways to create log:    1.create many log instance for each class  2.create only one instance for all class.     which way is better?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking for as this statement has me confused:

> Additional, I saw the usage of Rails, it also has only one instance named Rails.logger, wherever place I want write log, I call Rails.logger.info "xxxxx", this is very easy.

```
class AppName < Sinatra::Application

  configure do
    enable :logging
  end

  get '/' do
    logger.info "Hello world.. This is AppName!"
  end
end
```

Edit based on comment below:

It really depends on the structure of your application. However, one way I've done it before was to require all the other classes at the top of your main AppName class. Something like this: `Dir["./other-class-dir/*.rb"].each {|file| require file}` will work.  The other classes will now have access to the logger instance.

Comment: yes if you are in AppName class which is the subclass of Sinatra::Application,  you have the request.logger which is passed by request. so the logger.info is the instance of AppName.    But in other normal class , which has no parent class, does not has logger instance.

Comment: updated answer based on your comment. It depends on the structure of your application. But this is one way to accomplish it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so at which situation we should using only on log instance, and when should we create many log instance for each class?

Comment: I would say keep them in the same instance, unless you have a need or requirement to separate them. You can always separate them later :thumbs-up

Comment: ok, I will use the same instance first, and analysis whether should separate them later. Thank you